# Angular 17 ng serve proxy returns 302 instead of forwarding

Tags: angular, http-proxy, angular17

I'm trying to debug a Single Page Application and it's interactions with a Backend server. At the moment, I'm running the backend server on `localhost:8082` and `ng serve` runs on `localhost:4200`.

Here is the `proxy.conf.json` file I'm currently using:

```json
{
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8082",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  },
  "/subject/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/subject" : ""}
  }
}
```

Here is the current *serve* block in `angular.json`:

```json
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "falsehoods-client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "falsehoods-client:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
```

What I usually see is when I make a request to the backend server and use `http://localhost:4200/api/**` to do it, I usually see the 4200 server simply forward it to whatever backend server is specified in the target - in this case, on port 8082.

Now, here is what I'm seeing:

[image: Example of 302 response instead of forwarding in action]

Basically, I'm seeing a 302 response causing the browser to try to reach out to the backend server (and with more than the *api* portion of the path cut out for some reason.)

I know for a fact that the proxy config file is being used because when I tried omitting the *changeOrigin* fields, the `location` header in the 302 response would refer to `localhost:4200` instead.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: This seems like your backend's problem. Can you tell us more about the `/Auth/login` endpoint?

Comment: Yep. Turns out it was an issue with the backend. because of a faulty security set-up, every request was returning a 401 (and there was a context-path configuration i needed to fix). Not quite sure why this would cause the angular server to send a redirect, though.

Comment: Does the endpoint really return 401? Or does it redirect to login with 302?

Comment: Testing the backend with postman, it was returning 401. The ng server was returning a 302.